# mysql_query is unsuccessful. The database does not receive any data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on this application that is supposed to collect data from a form and send it to the database but for some reason, the database is not receiving any data. I tried using mysql_errno() and I received "Query was empty"

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $qualification = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qualification']);
            $position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
            $direct = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['direct']);
            $telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
            $cell = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cell']);
            $fax = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fax']);
            $email = $r['email'];
            $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
            $cityProvince = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cityProvince']);
            $postalCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postalCode']);
            $website = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['website']);

            $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mmg_business_card_logs` (`id`, `name`, `qualification`, `position`, `direct`, `telephone`, `cell`, `fax`, `email`, `address`, `cityProvince`, `postalCode`, `website`) 
                                                                VALUES ('', '{$name}', '{$qualification}', '{$direct}', '{$position}', '{$telephone}', '{$cell}', '{$fax}', '{$email}', '{$address}', '{$cityProvince}', '{$postalCode}', '{$website}')");
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Where's `$r` being populated from?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by removing the 'direct' field from my query. It turns out that the database table didnt have 'direct' as one of the columns and thats y it was unable to insert data

Comment: I take it that's what `mysql_error()` told you then.

Comment: Yes. Thats what mysql_error() told me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mmg_business_card_logs` ( `name`, `qualification`, `position`, `direct`, `telephone`, `cell`, `fax`, `email`, `address`, `cityProvince`, `postalCode`, `website`) 
                                                                VALUES ('$name', '$qualification', '$direct', '$position', '$telephone', '$cell', '$fax', '$email', '$address', '$cityProvince', '$postalCode', '$website')");
```

OR

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mmg_business_card_logs` (`id`, `name`, `qualification`, `position`, `direct`, `telephone`, `cell`, `fax`, `email`, `address`, `cityProvince`, `postalCode`, `website`) 
                                                                    VALUES ('121', '$name', '$qualification', '$direct', '$position', '$telephone', '$cell', '$fax', '$email', '$address', '$cityProvince', '$postalCode', '$website')");
```

Try this . If this will not work try echo $q and show me the output or try to execute that query in MySql